# how to create and make a custom.css file work

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I need to create custom.css file using local.xml. I tried adding this command
`<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css></stylesheet></action>` to local.xml file but it doesn't do anything, I can't edit my page. I'm not even sure where the custom.css saves. Could somone tell me the steps to do this with paths to the files?

Answer (score 2):

What @kothari posted will work, but since I can't comment on his answer, I'll answer your question about where it looks for it here.

Basically what this does:

```
<default>
     <reference name="head">
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Is it tells Magento to add the CSS in this file path:

`http://yourwebsite.com/skin/frontend/$package/$theme/css/custom.css`

`$package` and `$theme` referring to the active package and theme. For example, if you're using the default base theme, this would resolve to:

`http://yourwebsite.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/custom.css`

**It does NOT create the CSS file for you**, you have to create that CSS file and add it to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in your **local.xml**

```
<default>
         <reference name="head">
             <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find it. Do I need to create it? and if so whats the path?

Comment: First check page source it will call or not

Answer (score 0):

Adding new CSS

**`<theme-dir>/blank/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/newtheme.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**Remove static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts)**
To remove the static resources, linked in a page , make a change similar to the following in a theme extending file
**app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<head>
    <!-- Remove local resources -->
    <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <remove src="my-js.js"/>
    <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/compare.js" />

<!-- Remove external resources -->
    <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <remove src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" />
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove

Comment: the question is for M1.9 but your answer is for M2